# converting multi .html file into .txt files using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a directory on my drive and it has many.html files. Those files contain text when it opens with the browser. I have the following code to convert one .html into .txt file.
How can I make iterations for all files and save each file as .txt with its original name?

thank you in advance

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
markup = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/arc_Articlesww0c5e.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
markup.close()
f = open("arc_Articlesww0c5e.txt", "w")
f.write(soup.get_text())
f.close()
```

Comment: I am a new learner of python. Don't judge the other. I tried to iterate reading the files, but the output is an EMPTY file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might give you an idea of how to proceed:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

your_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive"

for file in os.listdir(your_dir):
    if file.endswith((".htm", ".html")):
        with open(os.path.join(your_dir, file)) as markup:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(markup.read())
        with open(file.split(".")[0]+".txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(soup.get_text())
```